# Авто выдача ролей по эмоджи

Tags: python, discord

Что я дела не так?
я нашел статью (https://question-it.com/questions/1160222/discordpy-kak-dat-konkretnuju-rol-pri-dobavlenii-reaktsii-na-konkretnoe-soobschenie)

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    # only work if it is the client
    if payload.member.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message_id == 750089806872314038 and reaction.emoji == '✅':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='ROLE NAME HERE')
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
```

но тут написано `@client.event` а у меня `@bot.event`
мой код выглядит так

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)

    # only work if it is the client
    if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message_id == 877636512682880 and reaction.emoji == '✅ ':
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' drugalek')
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
        await reaction.remove(payload.member)
```

но он не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с участниками серверов боту нужно выдать намерения (`intents`)

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

В этой строке у вас стоит пробел после эмоджи:

```
if payload.message_id == 877636512682880 and reaction.emoji == '✅ ':
```

Этот пробел мешает правильно сравнить значения строк. Правильно не так `'✅ '`, а так `'✅'`.

---

Ну и вполне возможно, что ошибка в `id` сообщения

```
if payload.message_id == 877636512682880
```

У вас точно указан `id` именно того сообщения, с которого нужно считывать реакцию?

---

Точно ли здесь указано правильное название роли?

```
name=' drugalek'
```

Вместо этого можете взять `id` роли и получить ее объект так:

```
roleid = # id роли
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=roleid)
```

---

`id` объектов `discord` можно получать нажав правой кнопкой мыши на объект - **Копировать ID**.

Для этого в настройках нужно включить режим разработчика

Comment: а можно как-то заменить эмоцию на id (что бы не саму эмодзи в коде использовать а только её id)

Comment: Вроде бы у стандартных `emoji` нет `id`. А вот для пользовательских можно использовать `emoji = bot.get_emoji(id)`. `id` можно получить написав в чат символ "\" перед `emoji`. Если пользовательское - то отправится название и `id`, а если стандартное - то просто символ unicode

Comment: можно поподробнее рассказать как сделать тоже самое но с  ```id пользовательского эмоджи ```. Я смог получить его ID но куда его вставить не понял

Comment: Используйте команду `emoji = bot.get_emoji()`, здесь в скобки надо передать `id` пользовательского эмоджи в виде `int`. После этого в объект `emoji` будет записан результат

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == channel_id:
        member = payload.member
        guild = bot.get_guild(guild_ID)
        emoji=payload.emoji
        if payload.emoji.name == 'emoji':
            role = member.guild.get_role(role_id)
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

guild_ID-это id сервера

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]